# WinError 10061 after making a POST request to my own localhost in Flask

Tags: python, http, flask, request

I have this code to do a POST request to my localhost:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    input_json = request.get_json()
    print('data received', input_json)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

    res = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/test', json={'name': 'Linus Torvalds'})
```

After run it and see it do not print anything to the console, I press CTRL+C and get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 170, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\http\client.py", line 1277, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\http\client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\http\client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\http\client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\http\client.py", line 972, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 182, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000026DB39B3688>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /test (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000026DB39B3688>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "only_post_request.py", line 15, in <module>
    res = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/test', json={'name': 'Linus Torvalds'})
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 117, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Carlitos\miniconda3\envs\python3.7\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /test (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000026DB39B3688>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión'))
```

I couldn't find a way to solve it. If I am not not wrong, for some weird reason I can not establish the connect to my own server.

I have Windows in Spanish, so the [WinError 10061] is translated to: `[WinError 10061] Cannot establish a connection as the target computer expressly denied that connection.`

Comment: Are you running a firewall of some sort? There’s one bundled with Windows which it encourages you to turn on; perhaps that’s running?

Comment: @Glyph I just tried disabling it, but sadly, the error persist.

Comment: Do you have a webserver running on port 5000?

Comment: @JohnGordon as far I understand (I'm new in python and flask), when app.run() sentence is executed server starts `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/` (extracted from the console).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, run server program,
then run client program in another shell of python and it will work.

While you are writing `requests` under `app.run` that `requests` will not run. And if you write before `app.run` then it gives error cuz server is not ready. So, run client from another file and run server from another one.

Or you can do the trick, write that `requests` script in some route. Like :

```
@app.route("/"):
def index():
    res = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/test', json={'name': 'Linus Torvalds'})
    return res
```

But for you it will not work cuz you aren't returing anything from `/test` you are just printing that data which is receive in `/test`.